# Kак запретить обновление элементов на фрагменте?

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Есть три фрагмента. На 1(стартовый) размещены две кнопки для перехода на другие фрагменты, на других по одной кнопки, чтобы вернуться обратно на 1(стартовый). На 2 фрагменте - два `Сheckbox` и на 3 фрагменте - `ImageView` для загрузки картинок из галерее. Фрагменты помещены во `ViewPager`. Если ставлю галочки `Checkbox` и делаю переходы между 1 и 2 фрагментами, то все нормально. Но если со 2 возвращаюсь на 1, а потом иду на 3 и потом возвращаюсь опять на 2, то `Checkbox` слетают. Такая же проблема и с картинкой для `ImageView`. Зато `Spinner`, который есть на 3 фрагменте работает нормально без сброса, как бы не переходил, между фрагментами.

Как запретить сброс? В чем может быть проблема? Куда смотреть?

Переключение между фрагментами делаю так:

```
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setPage(MainActivity.FRAGMENT_TWO);
```

Класс MainActivity где создаю фрагменты:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
public static final int FRAGMENT_ONE = 0;
public static final int FRAGMENT_TWO = 1;
public static final int FRAGMENT_THREE = 2;
public static final int FRAGMENTS = 3;
// адаптер фрагментов.     
private FragmentPagerAdapter _fragmentPagerAdapter;
// список фрагментов для отображения.
private final  List<Fragment> _fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
// ViewPager который будет все это отображать.
private ViewPager _viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // создаем фрагменты.
    _fragments.add(FRAGMENT_ONE, new FirstFragment());
    _fragments.add(FRAGMENT_TWO, new SecondFragment());
    _fragments.add(FRAGMENT_THREE, new TherdFragment());

    _fragmentPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {

 .....

};
    _viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    _viewPager.setAdapter(_fragmentPagerAdapter);
    _viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    _viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

}

```
 public void setPage(int page) {
    _viewPager.setCurrentItem(page, true); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поставить

`pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(>=2);` - это будет означать что относительно видимого фрагмента в кэше будет еще 2 фрагмента справа и два фрагмента слева, в вашем случае фрагмент удаляется и перерисовывается